# How to use array passed from executeWithArray(Object[]) in sql Query

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Iam  using the executeWIthArray() to pass a list. But when i try to use this array in Query it shows error.This is my code

```
QueryHelper.setSortOrderZero(pm).executeWithArray(list);
```

And in QueryHelper i have defined the function setSortOrderZero as follows:

```
public static Query setSortOrderZero(PersistenceManager pm) {
final Query query =  pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL","update TABLENAME set SORTORDER = 0 where ID in list");

return query;
```

}

But iam getting error.So is this the correct way to access the array????

```
ERROR:

   Exception in ProtectedFilter: Error executing SQL query "update    PROFILEARTADS set SORTORDER = 0 where PROFILE_ID in list".
  Mar 19, 2015 4:51:44 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse    mapMappableContainerException
     SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-  throwing to the HTTP container
    javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error executing SQL query "update PROFILEARTADS set SORTORDER = 0 where PROFILE_ID in list".
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:321)
    at com.giri.artsite.server.per.PersistenceDelegate.deleteAllArtsduplicate(PersistenceDelegate.java:8499)
    at com.giri.artsite.server.res.PersonServiceResource.deleteAllArts(PersonServiceResource.java:4681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in      your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'list' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1313)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1585)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1500)
    at c
```

Comment: so what is "list" in the SQL? It isn't a parameter clearly since a parameter in SQL is a "?" symbol. Also if you intend to have 1 parameter in the query you should pass 1 parameter value in ... NOT an array of parameter values

Comment: list is an array of integers. With executeWithArray() i thought i can pass array of values as paramaters and that can be used in the query. but it shows this error, so iam asking is it possible to pass array of values in executeWitharray()??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, in SQL a "parameter" has to be a "?" in the query; you have no parameter so no point passing in some array of parameters. 
What would make more sense would be

```
q = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "update TABLENAME set SORTORDER = 0 where ID in ?");
List values = ...
q.execute(values);
```

Comment: now another problem occured. Now the error has gone. but when iam sending 3 values in the list only the first one gets altered remaining are not affected.